# JWT Auth and Flutter : How to access a single model data

Tags: flutter, jwt, wordpress-rest-api, dio

I have an API with JWT Authentication enabled. I am trying to login a user and then update the user data. In JWT Auth, after login the server provides a token which is needed to update the user data. Now I can login a user and the server is giving me a token. I converted the token into LoginResponseModel.

These are the response model:

```
class LoginResponseModel {
String token;
String userNicename;

  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.userNicename});


  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token : json['token'],
      userNicename : json['user_nicename'],
      );}
  }
```

Although I can insert the token into model, I cannot access the token from my APIService class creating a LoginResponseModel class instance.

My approach of accessing the token is something like this:

```
LoginResponseModel loginResponseMode;
String token = loginResponseMode.token
var dio = Dio();
dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
// here is my network call code
```

But here i got null value of token. Would you please help me out how to access only the token from LoginResponseModel ? Thank you.

Comment: I see you're calling `return LoginResponseModel.toJson(response.data);` instead of `fromJson` in your code, is this on purpose?

Comment: I am so sorry. I eidited the code here so mistyped fromJson to toJson. I corrected the question body. Thanks. Apart from that, Is there any problem?

Comment: I don't see anything strange in your code. Possible details... Don't forget the application/json in the header. And be careful if you are adding "Bearer" twice (in my API, I receive the "Bearer" word in the token I receive from the server)

Comment: Hello @PabloInsua, Thanks for your comment. But i tried hitting the api using a fixed token. In that time, i can update user data. But whenever i try to use the token from response model, i got null value. The problem is the response data cannot be inserted to model after getting 200 ok response. That is why i cannot retrieve the token from model and use it as authorization to update user data.

Comment: Could it be that the token that you receive after login is in the Response's header and not in the data?

Comment: The token I am receiving is in the data. After decoding the response into json, I am receiving like:  {token: ABCDFGHIK,  user_email: abc@abc.com, so on...}